# Logo alignment on a certificate

Tags: page-layout, alignment

I have a certificate that I am designing.

[image]

Excuse the inconsistent text alignment. At the bottom, I have two logos. The red one is about twice as tall and half as long as the blue one. I am attempting to align them in the bottom corners in an aesthetically pleasing way. Currently, their bottom corners are aligned to the bottom margin corners of the page. However, Logo2 encroaches rather significantly on the signature lines, and I cannot shrink the logos without making them appear comically small.

What are best practices for aligning multiple logos of significantly different sizes/proportions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move them.

Put them at the top. Put them both to one side or the other and stack them. Put them both under the signatures. Put one at the top and one at the bottom.

If your Given Parameters are making something impossible, change one of the givens.

Answer (score 2):

Having both logos on one side could work well, but if it appears unbalanced because of it, I would recommend having them how you have mocked up above.

Play with the sizing of each logo to get some equality, and then make sure the space between the bottom and respective side of the certificate is the same for both logos.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with weight. Instead of putting them at the same inversed position (same distance left-right and bottom) I'd make the square one (left) slightly smaller and the short one (right) wider. Like archimedic objects in a bathtub :P